Is it possible to make Springboots @Transactional work with Kotlins Result?
I recently started using Kotlins Result in my Springboot Kotlin project.
One thing I realised it that it doesnt work together with Springs @Transactional annotation since we are wrapping errors in a Result.failure object rather than throwing them.
A bit of googling only lead me to a really old github issue:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27323
where they deemed it not popular enough to integrate with spring..
Is there any decent workaround to this problem?
Besides injecting a transactionManager into any service that needs transaction management and manually rolling back like so:
 fun upsert(): Result<Unit> {
    val transactionTemplate = TransactionTemplate(transactionManager)
    return transactionTemplate.execute { status ->
      Result.catch {
    
    multiple db operations here

}
        .onFailure { status.setRollbackOnly() }
    }!!
  }

Edit: For anyone finding this later, using custom aspects doesn't work directly with Kotlin's result because it is an inline function, if you still want to make it work you have to write a wrapper class around result and reference that in the custom aspect.
For now I decided to stick with manually injecting the transactionManager where I need it.

Write your own aspect and annotation which handles the Result or extend the existing one and configure transaction management manually. Also you don't need to inject the PlatformTransactionManager there is also a TransactionTemplate ready to use (instead of creating it).

Looking at the issue you linked, writing an aspect is exactly what is done, you can put the error handling code and transaction stuff inside that

@M.Deinum  This aspect in the github uses a third party Result library: com.github.michaelbull.result.Result but Result is nowaday integrated into Kotlin and from my understanding you cannot use aspects with those.

Why wouldn't you be able to do that? It is just a different return value. The aspect is for your @Transactional methods that return a Result. I fail to see class why using a different Result would break that. Additionally you can always ask to re-open the issue now that Result is part of Kotlin (if I understand you correctly), the Try from vavr is supported as well, so they might want to re-consider.

@M.Deinum I wasnt sure if aspects work  with a kotlin inline function. But I will give writing a custom aspect another try, thanks for the input!
